# How to calculate the limit of a sequence having a factorial $ \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\ln \left ( n \right )}{\left ( n! \right )^{\frac{1}{n}}} $

Tags: sequences-and-series

The limit of

> $$ \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\ln \left ( n \right )}{\left ( n! \right )^{\frac{1}{n}}} $$

Since the sequence is positive , can we find a sequence bigger having as a limit 0 ?

Comment: Use Stirling approximation.

Answer (score 2):

Use Stirling's Formula,

\begin{align}
n!\sim \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n
\end{align}
then it follows
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{e \ln n}{(2\pi n)^{1/2n} n} =0.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Assume first $n$ is even. Then there are exactly $n/2$ integers among $1,2,\dots , n$ that are $>n/2.$ Thus $n!> (n/2)^{n/2},$ giving $(n!)^{1/n}> (n/2)^{1/2}.$ So

$$\tag 1 \frac{\ln n}{(n!)^{1/n}}< \frac{\ln n}{(n/2)^{1/2}}.$$

Since $(\ln n)/n^{1/2} \to 0,$ the limit of $(1)$ is $0$ as $n\to \infty$ through even values.

The case of odd $n$ is basically the same.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.  First, take the log of the factorial:

$$\ln(n!)=\ln(1\times2\times\dots\times n)=\sum_{k=1}^n\ln(k)$$

Which is derived from log rules.  Then note that

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\ln(k)>\int_1^n\ln(x)\ dx=n\ln(n)-n+1>n\ln(n)-n$$

Thus,

$$\log(n!)>n\ln(n)-n$$

$$n!>\left(\frac ne\right)^n$$

$$(n!)^{1/n}>\frac ne$$

Which reduces your limit to the following:

$$0<\frac{\ln(n)}{(n!)^{1/n}}<e\frac{\ln(n)}{n}$$

which can be proven to go to zero in one application of L'Hospital's rule.